# Python print according to the shape of pyramid

Tags: python

**My csv data likes this:**
[image]

**I use this code to print:**

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
rs = pd.read_csv(r'D:/Clustering_TOP.csv',encoding='utf-8')
with open('D:/Clustering_TOP.csv','r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    rows = [row for row in reader]
csv_title = rows[0]
csv_title = csv_title[1:]
len_csv_title = len(csv_title)
for i in range(len_csv_title):
    for j in range(i,len_csv_title):
        print(str(rs[csv_title[i]].corr(rs[csv_title[j]])), end='\t')
    print()
```

**The result of printing is this，the format is not right：**
[image]

**But in fact,I want the printing likes pyramid,for example:**
[image]

**How to modify my code?**

Comment: Change `for j in range(i,len_csv_title):` to `for j in range(0, i+1):` should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello I am not 100% sure but I think your second for is the problem. Try this:

```
for i in range(len_csv_title):
    for j in range(i+1):
        print(str(rs[csv_title[i]].corr(rs[csv_title[j]])), end='\t')
    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue lies in your second 'for' loop. The range should be `for j in for j in range(len_csv_title)`, rather than in `range(i,len_csv_title)`.

Answer (score 0):

Change the below line:

```
for j in range(i,len_csv_title):
```

to:

```
for j in range(0,i+1):
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample code to print starts in the pattern you requested

```
def pyramidpattern(n):
  for i in range(0, n):
    for j in range(0, i+1):
      print("* ",end="")
    print("\r")

n=5
pyramidpattern(n)
```

Output:

```
* 
* * 
* * * 
* * * * 
* * * * *
```

Answer (score 0):

You need inverse back loop in your code. Just change the for loop and it works

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
rs = pd.read_csv(r'file',encoding='utf-8')
with open('file','r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    rows = [row for row in reader]
csv_title = rows[0]
csv_title = csv_title[1:]
len_csv_title = len(csv_title)

for i in range(len_csv_title):
    for j in range(0,i+1):
        print(str(rs[csv_title[i]].corr(rs[csv_title[j]])), end='\t')
    print()
```

> Try to change inverse for loop 
>   **for j in range(0,i+1):**